# Is there a well-defined, platform-independent way to get the size, in bytes, of a file opened in binary mode in C?

Tags: c, file

Normally I use the following code to determine the size of a file opened in `fp` in C:

```
size_t len;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
```

The C Standard (*§ 7.21.3, Files*) has the following footnote:

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

I have not observed any cases myself where this method has failed to produce the correct size for a binary file in C code myself, but according to the standard it is not well defined unless (at least) the file is open in text mode.

The other methods I know of for determining a file size are platform-dependent (like the `stat` family of functions, and `GetFileSize(Ex)` on Windows).

Is there, then, any platform-independent way to determine the length of a `FILE` open in binary mode using only standard C functions?

Comment: Read all of the data and count? Pretty much answering the question.

Comment: There is no nontrivial platform independent way to do it.